# AVG didn't give the correct value - Postgresql

Tags: average

I have a table in which there many redundant points, I want to select distinct points using (distinct) and to select the average of some row (eg. rscp). 
Here we have an example :

```
| id |  point                   |   rscp    |   ci
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 1  |  POINT(10.1192 36.8018)  |   10      |   701
| 2  |  POINT(10.1192 36.8018)  |   11      |   701
| 3  |  POINT(10.1192 36.8018)  |   12      |   701
| 4  |  POINT(10.4195 36.0017)  |   30      |   701
| 5  |  POINT(10.4195 36.0017)  |   44      |   701
| 6  |  POINT(10.4195 36.0017)  |   55      |   701
| 7  |  POINT(10.9197 36.3014)  |   20      |   701
| 8  |  POINT(10.9197 36.3014)  |   22      |   701
| 9  |  POINT(10.9197 36.3014)  |   25      |   701
```

What i want to get is this table below : (rscp_avg is the average of rscp of the redundant points)

```
| id |  point                   |   rscp_avg    |   ci
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| *  |  POINT(10.1192 36.8018)  |   11          |   *
| *  |  POINT(10.4195 36.0017)  |   43          |   *
| *  |  POINT(10.9197 36.3014)  |   22.33       |   *
```

---

I tried this, but it gave me a false average !!!!

```
select distinct on(point)
id,st_astext(point),avg(rscp) as rscp_avg,ci
from mesures
group by id,point,ci;
```

Thanks for your help (^_^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hamdoulah ! Thanks God !

I find the solution just now :

```
select on distinct(point)
id,st_astext(point),rscp_avg,ci
from
(select id,point,avg(rscp) over w as rscp_avg,ci
from mesures
window w as (partition by point order by id desc)
) ss
order by point,id asc;
```

The websites that help me are :

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html

http://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql-avg-function.php